# key={uniqueId} directive now working with template tag

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am looping through the records with key directive in template tag.
It was working for last few months and all of a sudden stopped working.
If I change template tag to div, it will work but want to understand why template tag start working with key.

Stopped working:

```
                <template key={eachOrder.id}>
```

Fix worked:

```
                <div key={eachOrder.id}>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was likely a bug if it was previously supported. Every top-level element inside a template iterator must have a unique key.

```
<template for:each={items} for:item="item">
    <div key={item.id}>Hello World</div>
</template>
```

This is how it is meant to work. You can read more in [Render Lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lists).

That said, you can omit the template if you don't need it:

```
<div for:each={items} for:item="item" key={item.id}>Hello World</div>
```

Comment: so you mean following was a bug? 
<template for:each={items} for:item="item">
    <template key={item.id}>Hello World</template>
</template>

this worked for more than a year. So we should use div with key instead of template?

Comment: @Vishal I honestly don't know what it was like before, but I've never seen anyone use `template key={item.id}`. If you look at the documentation, the key is usually attached to a non-`template` element, as in my example. In fact, the `template` isn't required at all.

Comment: @sdfcfox thank you